# Issues migrating Processes to flows using before and after flows pattern

Tags: visual-workflow

I am currently migrating my processes to flows. I did some research on patterns to be followed and found that before and after save flows are best suited for performance and scalability. I am dividing the processes into before save and after save flows using following criteria:

**Before Save-** When there is update on the triggering record.

**After Save-** When there is update on related record or some other action like sending email.

In many of the scenarios there are conditions which are updating the triggering record and also sending email and updating the related records in the same decision. So if i divide my processes into flows using above two methods then i would have to evaluate the conditions twice, one time in before save and the second time in the after save flow. This would consume CPU time. How can i work around it or is there any other pattern which is better than this.

Answer (score 0):

you can update the triggering record in After Save flows as well, it doesn't *have* to be in a Before Save flow. If you do that, you can have all your actions in one After Save flow and you'll only have one flow that runs.

I don't know whether it's more efficient in terms of performance/CPU time, but if you're not processing a large number of records at once, then I'd say just go with whatever's the most convenient from the admin perspective.